# Feature Request - Can we have a Picklist for 'Expertise in Matter' while creating a question?

Tags: feature-request

Can we have a Picklist for 'Expertise in Matter' with values something like 'Beginner', 'Intermediate', 'Expert' , 'Casual' while raising new Questions in Forum?

This will help to understand 
- what is the level of assistance and expertise the guy who raise the question is needed 
- also it will help all others those who are checking the question to give answer to it like what level of reply they can be given.

Hope this new Picklist will help people to give & identify the exact expertise that is needed for those raising the question and also for people trying to answer it.

Comment: Well written questions always receive higher quality answers than poorly written questions. Someone who's done their homework before asking their question will surely demonstrate that when they ask it, allowing someone with the right knowledge to quickly zero in on the answer if they have it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think we need a feature for this.

1. Those levels are subjective and may mean something else for everyone.
2. The aim of stackexchange sites is to have questions so focused and specific that they can easily be answered correctly. This site does not aim to have long conversations or exchanges of opinions. You either know the answer to a question or you do not.